# Empty textboxe.text values on btn click method

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I would like to know what I did wrong while i was creating form + some user controls, but after filling textbox field and submithing jquery dialog form, I got empty "tbClientName".text value. I can't find my mistake.

P.S When I am adding to the text property like Text="123", I always get 123, despite the fact that value either change or not

In addition to this, when I insert text, it bypasses require validator, so it looks like after that somewhere the value is deleted.

Looks like text property value lost after jquery codes, any suggestions?

Below is the corresponding code:

uc_addClient.aspx

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="uc_addClient.ascx.cs" Inherits="gamykla.Controls.uc_addClient" %>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    //setup new person dialog
    $('#newClient').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        draggable: true,
        title: "Pridėti užsakovą",
        open: function (type, data) {
            $(this).parent().appendTo();
        }
    });
});

function showDialog(id) {
    $('#' + id).dialog("open");
}

function closeDialog(id) {
    $('#' + id).dialog("close");
}
 </script>

<input id="btnOpenClientAddForm" type="button" value="Pridėti užsakovą" onclick="showDialog('newClient');" /> 
<asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<div id='newClient'>
<asp:Label ID="lblClientName" runat="server" Text="Užsakovo pavadinimas:"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="tbClientName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="tbClientName" ErrorMessage="Būtina įvesti užsakovo pavadinimą."></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:Button ID="btnAddClient" runat="server" Text="Pridėti" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClick="btnAddClient_Click"/>
</div>
```

Part from uc_addClient.aspx.cs

```
public partial class uc_addClient : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{   
    private string _clientName;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void btnAddClient_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         _clientName = tbClientName.Text;
         if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(NewClientName))
         {
             AddClient();
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a Master Page by chance? If so, you need to set `ClientIdMode="Static"` on your page in order to be able to select it that way. You could also just assign a class to your controls and select them that way.

Comment: I had asigned ClientIdMode="Static" on config pages, so it shouldnt be the reason

Comment: I guess I'm not following what you're trying to do. How are you expecting to set the textbox, with a value from the dialog? Also, the textbox should be using Text="123", not Value="123".

Comment: I`m expecting to get text of textbox in first line:                                                               protected void btnAddClient_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         _clientName = tbClientName.Text;

Answer (score -1):

**Please change your textbox declaration as follows:**

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="tbClientName" runat="server" value="123">

</asp:TextBox>
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: I meant by this that if i set text property manually before debug, i get value as it should be